# How to prevent tracking on a newly saved entity

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

In Entity Framework it's easy enough to get an existing item without tracking:

```
context.Widgets.AsNoTracking().Single(x=>x.Id == id);
```

What if I want to add a new item without tracking it once it's added? As soon as you do this:

```
context.Widgets.Add(newWidget);
```

the instance is tracked. Even if I detach the instance from the context, once it's attached again the context still keeps track of `OriginalValues` and introduces the usual issues with concurrent updates etc.

Is there a way to:

1. add a new entity

and/or:

2. attach an existing detached entity

to a `DbContext` while enforcing the equivalent `AsNoTracking` behaviour?

Comment: Struggling to think why you'd want to do this.  Could you just not add the entity in the first place? Perhaps you could explain your scenario a bit more?

Comment: Attaching *is* tracking! What do you mean? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
context.Widgets.Add(newWidget);
context.SaveChanges();
context.Entry(newWidget).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Edit:

The DbContext class, with its stateful nature, was made to track data changes. 
This approach made EntityFramework not suited to be used with types that are designed to be transient, like seem to be the "Widget" instance.

The code above should be doing the job: reuse a data structure to be used in a 'semi-persistent' context, but should be optimized with batching.

The reason I commented 'Use Dapper' is that I've been very frustrated in the past by EF, which creates a lot more problems than it solves. Using a stateless Orm is a lot more efficient.

Comment: got a downvote? well. Haven't used EF for years, but to me this answers the question "What if I want to add a new item without tracking it once it's added?" If I made a mistake, feel free to let me know.

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: oh I see! didn't know